# Retrieve SQL Server database information in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a program which will generate a SQL database schema including tables, view, keys, indexes, triggers, etc... like:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(....) ....
CREATE VIEW ViewName(...) ....
```

I know this is possible because SQL Server Management Studio does it (generate script command). However, how does it do it?

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention about permissions: I'm an owner of database (in most cases) but I'm **not** sys-admin. Would there be any difference?

Comment: like all table names?i.e list of tables?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with a schema in hand?  If you want to create a new database with the same schema then you need to determine a valid order in which to create objects.  That is a nontrivial problem.

Comment: @Habo, What is going to give me an error in this case? Only foreign keys?

Comment: @AlanDert - Views, triggers, stored procedures, user-defined functions, ... are all possible problems.  A related question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653391/how-can-i-script-an-ms-sql-server-database-with-proper-object-ordering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for list of tables:

```
foreach (DataRow row in schemaTbl.Rows)
{
listBox.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"]);
}
```

for columns from perticular table

```
object[] objArrRestrict;
objArrRestrict = new object[] {null, null, "Customers", null};
DataTable schemaCols;
schemaCols = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, objArrRestrict);
//List the schema info for the selected table
foreach (DataRow row in schemaCols.Rows)
{
listBox.Items.Add(row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting SQL Server only, [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) is very powerful.  This is the library that SQL Server Management Studio uses, and contains classes to convert database objects into scripts.

[The scripting example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Queries of database structure vary by sql server version.

The 2008 R2 page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which links to a [TABLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) page, which links to a [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) page, which links to a [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) page.

The sys.objects page has relevant samples.  This only gets you the table.  There are other system objects for column, triggers, views, ...

Answer (score 1):

If you truly mean generate you might want to look into Entity Framework / Code first approach that will essentially boostrap your db for you (Tables, etc).